# "Monetary" is for "money". In this vein, what adjective is used for status?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, synonyms

"Monetary" is for "money". In this vein, what adjective is used for status? Context:

> Nicolas Maduro abused his power for both monetary and ______ gains.

Answer (score 5):

How about a noun instead? *Status*. The nature of English allows us to use a noun adjunct:

> Gender-based zero-sum thinking reflects beliefs that women's status gains correspond directly with men's status losses. — [Zero-Sum Thinking and the Masculinity Contest](https://spssi.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/josi.12281)

Alternatively, flip it around but keep the noun. For example:

> Many women anticipate loss of hard-won gains of status and employment. — [First — and Last — Elections?](https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/opinions/1992/01/14/first-and-last-elections/eba23e97-beeb-42d3-b5bd-610aba0341cf/)

For your sentence, my preferred wording is a more drastic rewrite:

> Nicolas Maduro abused his power to gain both money and status.

Not all words have adjective forms and *status* is one of them.

Comment: "Money" felt a bit bland, so I thought I'd change it to its collateral adjective, "monetary," but then I got stuck on "status," I guess I have no choice but to use them as nouns. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Status is pretty much a synonym for Prestige.  ([See Thesaurus](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/status))

The adjective is  *prestigious*. I think that would probably fit your requirements.

Comment: I can't say how but I find this use of "prestigious" slightly off considering what I want to convey. Thank you for the suggestion, however.

Answer (score -1):

Just to add to Laurel's good answer that there are actually adjectives from ***status*** but they are useless for your sentence.

You have first ***statusy***

> ADJECTIVE **informal**
> conferring or having status or prestige ([collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/statusy))

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/statusy#:%7E:text=Definition%20of%20statusy,conferring%20prestige%20a%20statusy%20job) records the first use in 1962 and defines it as

> having, showing, or conferring prestige

It does not bring the meaning you need and it is too informal for the register of your sentence.

Then there is ***statusless*** which again would not be of any use for you as it means:

> Lacking or without official status.([OxfordLexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/statusless))

So, yes, you'd better stick with the nouns. And don't get tempted by [***statutory***](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/statutory) even though it slightly rhymes with *monetary*!

Comment: Probably not a good idea to be tempted by *statuary,* either.